# Condition only when the post is complete edited, not added or trash

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating some conditions in a function to return me only when the post is edited, not when it's created or deleted.

I've added some conditions but I still keep getting when I create or delete a post.

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'my_product_edited');

function my_product_edited( $post_id, $post_after, $post_before ) {

    // Check to see if we are autosaving
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;  

    // assure the post type
    if ( ! get_post_type($post_id) == 'product' ) 
        return;

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You want to know how to get access to do work **only when a post is edited**.

You do use a callback registered to the `post_updated` event.  However, we have to build a function that checks if this is an "edit" action.

### What determines an "edit" only action?

You'd think that `editpost` as the action value would tell you that it is an edit action.  Actually, this action is set when adding a new post as well as editing.  Why?

WordPress grabs the next record and assigns the post ID when you click on Add New.  The action's hidden input is set to `editpost` within the form's HTML.

Therefore, new and editing posts both use the `editpost` value for `$_POST['action']`.

We need to figure out what keys and values we can use then to differentiate between a new and edited post submission.

#### Add New Post HTML

Let's look at the HTML for the "Add New Post" form:

[image: Add New Post form HTML]

Take a look at the hidden field:

```
<input id="hiddenaction" name="action" value="editpost" type="hidden">
```

See how for a "new post" the hidden field "action" is set to a value of "editpost".

#### Edit Post HTML

Next, let's look at the HTML for the edit post interface:

[image: Edit Post form HTML]

Okay, see that it also uses the same value in the "action" hidden field.

```
<input id="hiddenaction" name="action" value="editpost" type="hidden">
```

#### What Field Can We Use?

Comparing the HTML fields above, you'll notice that the `_wp_http_referer` value is different between the Add New Post and Edit Post forms.  Aha, we can use that field in combination with the action field.

### Function to Check if Editing Post Submission

Let's put it together now and build a function that checks if this submission is for an "edit" only.

```
/**
 * Checks if the post's submission is an "edit"
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function is_post_submission_an_edit_task( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['action'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( 'editpost' != $_POST['action'] ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['_wp_http_referer'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $referer = '/wp-admin/post.php?post=' . $post_id . '&action=edit&message=';

    return $referer === substr( $_POST['_wp_http_referer'], 0, strlen( $referer ) );
}
```

The last couple of lines looks at the referer but not the `message=` value. Why? Because that message value can change.  Therefore, we clip that value and look at the rest of the string.

### Using The Function

Next, you want to register a callback to the event named `'post_updated'`.  This callback allows for 3 parameters to be passed to you.  You want at least 2 of them. Therefore, you need to specify:

- priority number, i.e. I set to 10
- number of arguments that you want, e.g. I set it to 3

Here's the code:

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'process_after_product_edited', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Process work when the product has been edited.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param int     $post_id      Post ID.
 * @param WP_Post $post_after   Post object following the update.
 * @param WP_Post $post_before  Post object before the update.
 */
function process_after_product_edited( $post_id, $post_after, $post_before ) {

    if ( ! is_post_being_updated( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $post_after->post_type != 'product' ) {
        return;
    }

    // now you can do your work

}
```

The first check verifies if this is an "edit" submission.  If no, we bail out as there's nothing to do.

The second check determines if the post type is a product, per your specific use case.  If no, bail out as there's nothing to do.

Otherwise, you can put your code at the bottom as "Yes, this product was edited."

Comment: Thanks, but when I add a product there I get notification of function.

Comment: @ctovelox What do you mean? Please clarify what "get a notification of function" means.

Comment: sorry let me clarify, I'm using this function to send me an email when a product is edited. But when I create a product I am also receiving emails.

Comment: @ctovelox It needed much more than just `editpost`.  I updated the answer for you. Now the code ONLY triggers on an edit submission and not a new post or trash.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following check after your post type check.

```
if (!isset($_POST['action']) || $_POST['action'] != 'editpost')
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to do what I have already accomplished in my plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tld-woocommerce-downloadable-product-update-emails/

Hopefully it helps you.